# Split tuple In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write some Python to take two tuples and split it into the separate words, later use these words for comparison. But the split method is not working. Can anyone help i am new to python.(code and error is given)

```
for i in range(3, 8):
    cell_1=i, assign_sheet.cell(row=3, column=2).value
    cell_2=i, assign_sheet.cell(row=3, column=3).value
    s1= cell_1.split(" ")
    s2= cell_2.split(" ")
    temp=[]
    for w in s1:
        if w in s2:
            temp.append(w)
            print temp
```

[error given in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0AjN.png)

Comment: Well, the error message is very clear: "*tuple object has no attribute split*". Maybe you want to iterate on its elements?

Comment: The tuple contains objects, not words.

Comment: This code does not run.  Can you please fix your indentation?  To get the elements of a tuple, you can just do: `s1, s2 = cell_1`

Comment: spilt is the string object's method, cannot be used on tuple.

Comment: Don't post code or error messages as an image, please: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1025391

Comment: can't unpack give me an error

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a tuple in the first place? If you are trying to split the value in a spreadsheet cell, Use this

```
for i in range(3, 8):

    cell_1 = assign_sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    cell_2 =assign_sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
    s1= cell_1.split(" ")
    s2= cell_2.split(" ")
    temp=[]
    for w in s1:
        if w in s2:
            temp.append(w)
            print temp
```

Comment: this method only repeat for only row=3 but i want it for all my row elements

Comment: that's really a different question which was another error in your code. but see the update. change row=3 to row=i

Answer (score 0):

Print the words in column 2 and 3 for every row between 3 and 8

```
for i in range(3, 8):
    # get cell 1 and 2
    cell_1 = assign_sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    cell_2 = assign_sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value

    # split on spaces (gives a list per cell)
    s1 = cell_1.split(" ")
    s2 = cell_2.split(" ")

    # combine lists and print them
    temp = s1 + s2
    print temp
```

Comment: how can i store these values back in excel sheet?

Comment: Ask a seperate question for that problem! And please explain how you want it to be stored in Excel (with an example) and add the python library you are using for excel interaction!!